# saving from select into outfile mySQL onto client computer

Tags: mysql, select, into-outfile

```
select * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '/n' from ancestor;
```

So I run this command, and it executes normally. I run it again, and it errors because it says that result.txt already exists. When I check within the tmp folder on my computer, I don't see the file there. I have seen many people run into similar errors, and many people's responses have been that it gets saved on the host server. And it does! Which is fine. But here is the thing. I need it to save on my client computer. How do I make it so it works on the client? Also, the client is running mac os x. Also, the person who uses the client uses workbench and would prefer not to use terminal. Because I know there is the -e command for terminal but I don't know how to replicate that on workbench.

Comment: not running again is expected. mysql will **NOT** overwrite a file that already exists as a security measure. Make sure the user you're on as has rights to see the file. don't know if osx will hide files you don't have rights to, but if it doesn, then you're probably not allowed to SEE that result.txt file.

Comment: Yeah I figured out my old problem. But now i have a new one which is why i edited my question :(

Comment: no, you can't have the mysql server write a file to another machine. that'd mean the server process has to have write permissions and access to the client machine. you do **NOT** want this to be possible. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html  `If you want to create the resulting file on some other host than the server host, you normally cannot `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I feel like a fool, but there is an export button in mySQL workbench that allows you to export the result of any query. This avoids the whole issue I've been having. Sorry to trouble you guys. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OSX, files in the /tmp directory are hidden in the finder.

You could [try this](http://lifehacker.com/188892/show-hidden-files-in-finder) to show hidden files in the finder.

Comment: that actually answered my previous question before I edited it. Thank you so much! But now I have a new problem :(